# I can't get puddletag to open?

Tags: 15.10

When I tap the puddletag icon, it flashes a little, and then doesn't do anything.  for an instant, there's a small gray window in the middle of the screen (I don't think there is anything on it, but it goes by very fast).  I have tried removing and reinstalling, purging and reinstalling, and it doesn't seem to work.  if I try to open from the command line, I get the following:

```
name@computer:~$ puddletag
puddletag Version: 1.0.5
Locale: en_US
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/puddletag", line 350, in <module>
    win = MainWin()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/puddlestuff/puddletag.py", line 315, in __init__
    winactions, self._docks = create_tool_windows(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/puddlestuff/puddletag.py", line 92, in create_tool_windows
    p = PuddleDock(z[0], z[1], parent, status)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/puddlestuff/puddleobjects.py", line 2193, in __init__
    control = control(status=status)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/puddlestuff/mainwin/artwork.py", line 61, in __init__
    self.picwidget = PicWidget()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/puddlestuff/puddleobjects.py", line 1530, in __init__
    self.label = ArtworkLabel()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/puddlestuff/puddleobjects.py", line 1421, in __init__
    pal.setBrush(self.backgroundRole(), QBrush(QPalette.Window))
TypeError: QBrush(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'ColorRole'
name@computer:~$
```

How should I open Puddletag?

apt-cache policy puddletag output:

```
name@computer:~$ apt-cache policy puddletag
puddletag:
  Installed: 1.0.5-1
  Candidate: 1.0.5-1
  Version table:
 *** 1.0.5-1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: `puddletag` works in my fresh installed Ubuntu Wily VM. [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy puddletag`.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this seems to be a reported bug with PuddleTag.

You can see the [Debian](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=791752) and the [Arch Linux](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/45319) bug reports at their respective links.

According to those reports it looks like this was caused by the 4.11.3 -> 4.11.4 upgrade of `python-qt4`.

Comment: You can't install with `python-qt4=4.11.3+dfsg-1`, because the package is a Vivid package and the version **isn't** available in the Wily repositories and also installing this package doesn't help.

Comment: @A.B. Well, I didn't have a Wily system at the time, so I was going based off what I found online. That's why I specifically said "you can *try* to fix this" in my answer. I'll remove that part of my answer.